# AWS Lambda Malformed Lambda with Proxy Integration when accessing event

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Issue at hand : Malformed Lambda exception only when accessing event data.

When I access the event, API Gateway returns an "Internal server error".
A simplified use case of something I'd like to do would be to access the values of a key given to the Lambda from a POST request, proxy integration is used so there should be no need for template mapping.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   items = {}
   items["hello"] = "name"

   itemsarray = []
   for key, value in event.items() :
       itemsarray.append(key + ":" + value)

   return {
       'statusCode': 200,
       'isBase64Encoded': False,
       'body' : json.dumps(items),
       'headers': {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
   };
```

---

Error Message from API Gateway, Lambda itself returns no errors on the code.

---

```
Thu Feb 15 13:24:51 UTC 2018 : Received response. Integration latency: 742 ms
Thu Feb 15 13:24:51 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "must be str, not NoneType", "errorType": "TypeError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/lambda_function.py", 9, "lambda_handler", "itemsarray.append(key + \":\" + value)"]]}
Thu Feb 15 13:24:51 UTC 2018 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Thu Feb 15 13:24:51 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 502
```

JSON Post Data

---

> {   "dummy": "hello",   "data": "world" }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question to save someone hours of pain in years to come. I was tempted to do "NVM got it". Either way here you go.

The event body returns a string.

> data = json.loads(event['body'])

Now for interacting with it. If we had a JSON structure like

```
{
"someVar": "out",
  "data": {
    "message": "another out"
  }
}
```

> data['data']

would return us *"message": "another out"*

**NOTE**
In the lambda compiler online. It gives the following error, but once interacting with it via something like postman or API Gateway it works fine. It seems to give a false negative that threw me for an extended period of time.

```
'body': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line N, in lambda_handler
    var= json.loads(event['body'])
KeyError: 'body'
```

Now raise a beer for my hours wasted and thank God stack overflow is a thing

Comment: I don't understand how you solved it. Im having the same error rn actually. Well if i passed a json in my apigateway as {"foo":"bar"}. 
How am i supposed to access that in my python?

like this? 
```foo = json.loads(event["body"])["foo"]```


@eternal_atom

Comment: Oh nvm. Got it! Thanks mate!